# What's the easiest approach to showing a table of countries in an ASP.Net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my method that returns an IQueryable of Countries:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace InternationalShipments.Repository
{
    public class CountryRepository
    {
        ShipmentsEntities db = new ShipmentsEntities();

        public IQueryable<Country> FindAll()
        {
            return db.Countries;
        }

        public Country Get(int id)
        {
            return db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }

        public void Add(Country country)
        {
            db.Countries.AddObject(country);
        }

        public void Delete(Country country)
        {
            db.Countries.DeleteObject(country);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My intent is to show a form that lets you create new countries and on the same page, continue to display all countries in the DB. So if a user adds a new country, it should display in the table above.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a [Repeater](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-repeater-control).  Using that you can easily bind your data to the control and create an HTML template for the output.  If you want something with a little more power, you can try the [DataGrid](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020135207/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/040502-1.aspx) or [Gridview](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)

Comment: I went with a GridView. Just grdView.DataSource = repo.FindAll() and presto.

Answer (score 0):

I think a Gridview using a Linq to SQL or SQL Datasource would fit the bill.  I recall that the gridview can be customized to include an "add record" feature as well as the ability to edit returned records.